# Нужно ли здесь двоеточие? (Цитата внутри предложения)

Tags: пунктуация

А последние два месяца, когда полицейские в участках, где я ночевал, недоверчиво смотрели на незваного гостя: «Туристы, мол, в полиции не спят», прикрывался этим термином как щитом.

Comment: Кто прикрывался, каким термином? Чего-то недостает в этом предложении.

Comment: Конечно: я же не выложу сюда весь текст книги...

Comment: Как показывает опыт, отсутсвие контекста может приводить к неправильному пониманию вопроса. В данном случае у меня есть подозрение, что фраза неудачно составлена, но без контекста ничего утверждать не могу.

Comment: Упоминаемый термин - "холидей".

Answer (score 1):

Здесь лучше использовать **вставную конструкцию** (тире иди скобки):

А последние два месяца, когда полицейские в участках, где я ночевал, недоверчиво смотрели на незваного гостя ― **туристы, мол, в полиции не спят** ― прикрывался этим термином как щитом.